# Bulleted lists not working in site pages SP 365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, html, outlook

I've searched high and low and no joy, hope someone can help.  We have a SP team site which has publishing enabled.  The site page I've authored is an Index with multiple links to other pages and documents, and relies heavily on

- HTML to make it readable. I have an alternate css document explicitly referenced in Site Master Page Settings with this

```
 ul{
    list-style:disc;
 }
```

I've tried embedding code to run the same css file at the server.  We use classic view.  No errors are displayed by the script editor.  I saw a comment that linking the SP site to Outlook might be stripping out HTML, so I disconnected my own Outlook mapping and asked the other site owner to do the same.  We both did this via Outlook only, and I cannot locate any settings to tell SP to unmap the site.  Interestingly, a subsite I created does not experience this problem - it displays bullets correctly.  Can someone please point me to:

Either a way to tell SP that Outlook is now unmapped and quit
stripping HTML, A way to force the HTML to render

TIA folks, eager to hear any suggestions ...
Larry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul{ list-style:disc !important ; }
```

Also, are you sure your CSS file is being loaded? (Correct URL and permissions, and is checked in and published?)

Comment: Thank you Mike - yes to correct URL and permissions, and yes checked in and published.  I changed the CSS as per your note and unfortunately, no luck.  The embedded script looks like this:

<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/SiteAssets/somefile.css" runat="server">.  Oh, and the URL for the alternate CSS file specified in the site settings is correct.